# Integral like a norm instead of sum

Tags: integration, normed-spaces

A Rienmann integral is defined as:

$\int_a^b f(x)\ dx=\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}f\left(\displaystyle\frac{b-a}{n}\cdot i+a\right)$

I was wondering if their exists literature on a more generalized concept which is derived from the $p$-norm:

$\int_a^{b,p} f(x)\ dx=\sqrt[p]{\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left|f\left(\displaystyle\frac{b-a}{n}\cdot i+a\right)\right|^p}$

The definition can both be seen as a generalized integral or generalized norm...

Comment: What about p-norms : $(\int |f(t)|^p)^{1/p}$ ?

Comment: Is their some calculus defined on that part?

Comment: You can show that for p norms when p goes to infinity you have on interval I for the sake of simplicity here : $(\int_I |f|^p)^{1/p}\rightarrow ||f||_\infty = \sup_I |f|$ (this comment was related to yours which you removed)

Comment: Appologies for post-editing. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to define amounts exactly to the $p$-norm: 
$$
\sqrt[p]{\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left|f\left(\displaystyle\frac{b-a}{n}\cdot i+a\right)\right|^p}=\left(\int_a^b|f(x)|^p\,dx\right)^{1/p}
$$
whenever $|f|^p$ is integrable.